# AGOL Published Service - Changing Label Decimals

Tags: labeling, fields-attributes, arcgis-online, feature-service

I published a service from ArcGIS Pro and would like to change layer decimal places for the label in AGOL. Option A is to republish and correct the labels in ArcGIS Pro but wanted to see if there is an option to update the labels in AGOL.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to just add that feature service to a map in Pro through the Portal in the Catalog (be sure you are signed in to your AGOL account in Pro). You can quickly find the service by just pasting its item ID from the URL  to the *Search My Content* search box in the Catalog. From there change the attributes. When you save your edits they will be reflected in AGOL. You don't have to republish.

- Instructions on how to round the numbers in an attribute table to a given number of decimal places: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011204

Feature service item ID in the URL
[image]

Catalog in Pro
[image]